# Stationary points minimizing function

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

I'm minimizing a function in 2 variables and I have to find the stationary points, so I put both first derivatives equal to 0, and I obtain this:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
{2e^{(2x+y)}+4x-y-3=0} \\
{e^{(2 x + y)} - x + 2 y=0}
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

And, according to all my math knowledge, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it has no solution. How should I go on from here?

Comment: If there are no solutions then that means there are no stationary points.

Comment: But what makes you think that there are no solutions to the two equations that you posted?

Comment: So it has no minimum? @supinf

Comment: Because I arrive in a point where I have $e^{something}=somethingelse$ and while $e$ is always positive, $somethingelse$ is not. And I wasn't sure it was a good conclusion, so I tried to put it on wolfram, and it gives me no solutions :/ @supinf

Comment: If there was no solution (as you initially thought) then yes, it would mean that there is no minimum. But due to the answer of PierreCarre it looks like there can be solutions

Comment: Ok, thank you! I saw it and I totally agree, it just confuse me how to reach this conclusion :/

Comment: @ValentinaSau the RHS you mention does not need to be always positive, just needs to be positive when $(x,y)$ is a solution of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from the second equation you get $e^{2x+y} = x-2y$ so, going back to the first equation, you get $2x-4y+4x-y-3 = 0$, i.e. $y = \frac 65 x -\frac35$. So it amounts to solve
$$
e^{\frac{16}{5}x-\frac 35}-x +\frac{12}{5}x-\frac 65 = 0
$$

which has in fact one solution... $x \approx 0.173704$. So, there is a single stationary point $(x^*,y^*)\approx (0.173704 , -0.391555)$. Assuming that the equations you wrote down are exactly the partial derivatives and not some simplification, you will see that the Hessian matrix is positive definite at the stationary point and so the stationary point is a local minimum. In fact you can see that the Hessian matrix is positive definite in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so the function in strictly convex and the stationary point is a global minimum.

Comment: @ValentinaSau, no the equation I mentioned needs to be solved numerically. Can you post the expression of $f$? Maybe there is some error computing the derivatives...

Comment: Thank you so much! I imagine there's not a easy way without calculator that may lead me to find the solution, right? Anyway thanks!

Comment: The initial equation is: $2x^2-xy+y^2-3x+e^{2x+y}$

Comment: Even without solving the system, you can show that it has one and only one solution... Using convexity you show that the solution of the system is a global minimum.